# Cross Product Properties

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I wish to know if there are other properties of the vector product that I should know apart from the standard ones : distributive over addition multiplication by a constant   and   $a\times b=-b\times a$
The fact is I am stuck on this proof since 3 hours please help

Show that for three points A,B,C (non collinear) of space and 
For any point M ,

$\vec{MA}\times \vec{MB}+\vec{MB}\times \vec{MC}+\vec{MC}\times \vec{MA} = \vec{AB}\times \vec{AC}$

Comment: Please format your questions using Mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Not that it'll necessarily help here, but it can be often useful to draw a diagram to visualise it.

Comment: OK I've been to the page I can't see the code for vectors

Comment: I've edited your question - `\vec{???}` does it

Comment: Alright thanks I'll do it next time

Comment: If I may ask does the technology stack exchange uses is the same as LATEX?

Comment: I think quite a lot of things are similar, but there might be some differences - I'm not too sure. Equations are enclosed in `$` or `$$`, while in Latex `\(...\)`. Perhaps this helps https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tex-math-markup-is-sorely-needed. It says here, 'TeX is surrounded by dollar signs' so I would assume basically the same, although I'm not 100$ as I don't know much about it

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to answering this question is knowing that $\vec{XY}=\vec{ZY}-\vec{ZX}$.

If you let $M$ be the origin the equation you need to prove becomes:

$$\vec{a}\times \vec{b}+\vec{b}\times \vec{c}+\vec{c}\times \vec{a} = (\vec{b}-\vec{a})\times (\vec{c}-\vec{a})$$

You also need to know that $\vec x\times\vec x=\vec0$.

Comment: Yeah thanks that one is easy to prove from the right but is that assumption valid??

Comment: @arsenestein Which assumption? You can obtain the first identity from drawing a picture.

Comment: I mean letting m to be the origin

Comment: That's not really an assumption, but a choice of coordinate system, and I only did that as $\vec{a}=\vec{OA}$ is common convention. You could explicitly do something like 'Let $\vec{a}=\vec{MA}$, ...' instead, of course.

Comment: Alright thank you very much